# What are the available compilers for Trapped-Ion Quantum Computing Architecture?

Tags: programming, trapped-ion, compiling

I am looking for a compiler to compile a high-level quantum circuit for the Trapped-Ion Quantum Computing architecture, i.e. a compiler that can translate a high-level circuit to native gates of the TI hardware (single-qubit rotations and 2-qubit MS gate) in an optimized manner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can compile gates to native trapped ion gates via [cirq.ion.ConvertToIonGates](https://quantumai.google/reference/python/cirq/ion/ConvertToIonGates). For example:

```
import cirq

q0, q1 = cirq.LineQubit.range(2)

circuit = cirq.Circuit(
    cirq.H(q0),
    cirq.CNOT(q0, q1),
    cirq.measure(q0, key='m')
)

print("Circuit:")
print(circuit)
# Prints
# Circuit:
# 0: ───H───@───M('m')───
#           │
# 1: ───────X────────────

ion_circuit = cirq.ion.ConvertToIonGates().convert_circuit(circuit)
print("Ion Circuit:")
print(ion_circuit)
# Prints
# Ion Circuit:
# 0: ───PhX(1)───────────MS(0.25π)───PhX(-0.5)^0.5───S^-1───M('m')───
#                        │
# 1: ────────────────────MS(0.25π)───PhX(1)^0.5──────────────────────
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you can do this actually can be done with Qiskit as well. You just need to specify the *basis gates* sets you want to use under the [transpile function.](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.compiler.transpile.html)

**For example:** If I have the following circuit

[image]

which can be generated with Qiskit as:

```
from qiskit import QuantumRegister, ClassicalRegister, QuantumCircuit
from numpy import pi

qreg_q = QuantumRegister(2, 'q')
creg_c = ClassicalRegister(2, 'c')
circuit = QuantumCircuit(qreg_q, creg_c)

circuit.h(qreg_q[0])
circuit.x(qreg_q[1])
circuit.cx(qreg_q[0], qreg_q[1])
circuit.measure(qreg_q[0], creg_c[0])
circuit.measure(qreg_q[1], creg_c[1])
circuit.draw( 'mpl',style={'name': 'bw'}, plot_barriers= True, initial_state = True, scale = 1)
```

Now, if I am targeting a Trapped-ion system then instead of using CNOT as part of the native gate, we use Mølmer–Sørensen gate but this gate is equivalent to $R_{XX}$ gate when using two qubits. So I can transpile my circuit using this $R_{XX}$ gate and single qubit rotation as my native gates. We can do that as follow:

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, transpile
trans_qc = transpile(circuit, backend = None, basis_gates = ['rx', 'ry', 'rz', 'rxx'])
```

the transpiled circuit, `tans_qc`, is now have the form:

[image]

---

Furthermore,  if you want to actually simulate this on a trapped-ion hardware and potentially running on one then I would suggest you to sign-up for a **free** account with [AQT](https://www.aqt.eu/) (Alpine Quantum Technologies). Now you can actually set your `backend` using AQT system and transpile your circuit based on that.

```
from qiskit_aqt_provider import AQTProvider
aqt = AQTProvider('***********************')
AQT_backend = aqt.backends.aqt_qasm_simulator

trans_qc = transpile(circuit, backend = AQT_backend,  optimization_level = 3)
trans_qc.draw( 'mpl',style={'name': 'bw'}, plot_barriers= True, initial_state = True, scale = 1)
```

Which will output:

[image]

Use this [documentation here](https://github.com/qiskit-community/qiskit-aqt-provider) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You can compile to the native gateset of the Quantinuum ion trap devices $\{\text{Rz}, \text{PhasedX}, \text{ZZPhase}\}$ using the [pytket-quantinuum](https://tket.quantinuum.com/extensions/pytket-quantinuum/) package.

See [this answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/34571/how-do-i-compile-a-circuit-to-the-native-gateset-of-quantinuums-trapped-ion-dev/34572#34572) for more details.