# Can Qiskit decompose circuits into non-IBMQ basis gate sets?

Tags: qiskit, circuit-construction

Let `circ` be a `QuantumCircuit` object. Running `circ.decompose()` returns a circuit that consists entirely of gates native to IBMQ computers (single-qubit operations + CNOT).

I'm interested in decomposing `circ` into a circuit consisting of gates native to ion-trap quantum computers (that is, single-qubit gates + Mølmer–Sørensen). Is there a way to do this in Qiskit?

Comment: According to this answer: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/15617/9474. This is can be done in Qiskit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify the target basis for instance using `transpile`:

```
from qiskit import transpile

target_basis = ['rx', 'ry', 'rz', 'h', 'cx']
decomposed = transpile(circuit,
                       basis_gates=target_basis, 
                       optimization_level=0)  # 0 for no optimization, 3 is max
```

Note that

- the target basis should be complete (e.g. `rz h cx`). For high optimization levels (2 or 3) you might have to include `u` and `cx` so all optimization passes work correctly.
- I don't think the Molmer-Sorensen gate is currently supported as basis gate

Comment: The Molmer-Sorensen gate is supported as a generalized gate - https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.library.GMS.html#qiskit.circuit.library.GMS