# How do I compile a circuit to the native gateset of Quantinuum's trapped-ion devices?

Tags: compiling, trapped-ion, pytket

Suppose I have a quantum circuit defined in pytket, qiskit or some other quantum SDK.

How do I compile my circuit to be in the native gateset of the Quantinuum trapped ion device/emulators?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the [pytket-quantinuum](https://tket.quantinuum.com/extensions/pytket-quantinuum/) extension. This is installed as a separate python package.

I'll show an example. First I'll build a quantum circuit and then compile it to the native gateset.

```python
from pytket import Circuit
from pytket.circuit.display import render_circuit_jupyter

circ = Circuit(2)
circ.H(0)
circ.Rz(0.75, 0)
circ.CX(0, 1)
circ.measure_all()

render_circuit_jupyter(circ) # Draw circuit
```

[image]

Here I've defined a pytket `Circuit` by hand. You could also load in a `Circuit` from a QASM file or convert a qiskit `QuantumCircuit` using the [pytket-qiskit](https://tket.quantinuum.com/extensions/pytket-qiskit/api.html#pytket.extensions.qiskit.qiskit_to_tk) extension.

Next we can initialise our `QuantinuumBackend`. This is the interface between pytket and the device/emulator.

```python
from pytket.extensions.quantinuum import QuantinuumBackend

# Backend for the H1-1 device
h1_backend = QuantinuumBackend("H1-1", machine_debug=True) 
compiled_circ = h1_backend.get_compiled_circuit(circ)

render_circuit_jupyter(compiled_circ) # Draw compiled circuit
```

[image]

We see that our circuit is now in the native gateset of the H1-1 device. This gateset is $\{\text{Rz}, \text{PhasedX}, \text{ZZPhase}\}$. The $\text{Rz}$ gate isn't needed here.

The entangling $\text{ZZPhase}$ gate is defined as follows...

$$
\begin{equation}
\text{ZZPhase}(\theta) = \exp\Big(-i \frac{\pi \theta}{2} (Z \otimes Z )\Big)
\end{equation}
$$

This parameterised gate is quite expressive and is maximally entangling for $\theta = 0.5$.

The $\text{PhasedX}$ gate is simply a sequence of single qubit rotations.

$$
\begin{equation}
\text{PhasedX}(\alpha, \beta) = \text{Rz}(\beta)\, \text{Rx}(\alpha)\, \text{Rz}(-\beta)
\end{equation}
$$

A couple points are worth noting here.

1. Firstly I've set the `machine_debug` flag to `True` when initialising the `QuantinuumBackend`. This allows me to compile a circuit without needing Quantinuum credentials. If I don't use this I'll be prompted for a login.
2. By default `QuantinuumBackend.get_compiled_circuit` performs a tailored sequence of optimisations to the input circuit. See the [docs](https://tket.quantinuum.com/extensions/pytket-quantinuum/index.html#default-compilation) for details.